# Scroll to the top of slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle, scrolltop

I am relatively new to the web development scene and have ran in to some issues with jQuery. I am creating a food menu and using the slideToggle functionality to display different sections of the menu.

What I am trying to do is so when the toggle (.food-item) is clicked, the viewport will scroll to the top of the relevant clicked toggle.

Here is a current sample of the mark up:

```
<div class="full-menu-container">
        <div class="menu-area">
            <!-- PRODUCT START --> 
            <div class="food-item">
                <h1 class="menu-title">Mains</h1>
                <?php if(get_field('menu_mains')): ?>
                    <div class="food-content">
                        <h2 class="food-header">Specials available, see today’s hot Specials Board</h2>
                        <?php while(has_sub_field('menu_mains')): ?>
                            <div class="menu-spacer">
                                <h2><?php the_sub_field('item_name'); ?></h2>
                                <div class="food-description">
                                    <p><?php the_sub_field('item_description'); ?></p>
                                    <h2><?php the_sub_field('item_price'); ?></h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <!-- PRODUCT END --> 
            <!-- PRODUCT START --> 
            <div class="food-item">
                <h1 class="menu-title">sandwiches and melts</h1>
                <?php if(get_field('menu_sandwiches_melts')): ?>
                    <div class="food-content">
                        <p>Served on hand-cut white or malted wholemeal bloomer bread with fresh salad garnish and Pipers crisps.<br/><b>Add a mug of soup £2</b></p>
                        <?php while(has_sub_field('menu_sandwiches_melts')): ?>
                            <div class="menu-spacer">
                                <h2><?php the_sub_field('item_name'); ?></h2>
                                <div class="food-description">
                                    <p><?php the_sub_field('item_description'); ?></p>
                                    <h2><?php the_sub_field('item_price'); ?></h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <!-- PRODUCT END --> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the Jquery I have:

```
jQuery(".food-content").first().slideToggle(500);
            jQuery('.food-item').click(function(){
                jQuery(".menu-container, .full-menu-container").siblings().find('.food-content').slideUp();
                jQuery(this).find('.food-content').slideDown();
```

As it stands I have tried to use the scrollTop to try and return the viewport to the clicked toggle, in this case being the .food-item div, so far with no success.

Here is what I have tried to implement with no luck:

```
if(jQuery('.food-content').is(":visible")){
                         jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery(this).offset().top})
                    }
```

Any one able to assist further? 
thanks!

Comment: So are you trying to open up the .food-content and scroll down to it?

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but you would save quite some time by writing e.g. `$('.food-content')` instead of `jQuery('.food-content')`, assuming you don't use `jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: @Chizzle When .food-item is clicked it will display .food-content. Since there is 10 sections what I am trying to achieve is for the display to move with the toggling so you don't have to manually scroll to the top of the open one when it's clicked. instead the viewport will animate to the top of the relevant open one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you described. 
Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o1s98kph/

```
jQuery(".food-content").hide();
jQuery(".food-content").first().slideToggle(500);

jQuery('.food-item').click(function(){
    var thisContent = jQuery(this).find('.food-content');
    if( ! thisContent.is(":visible")) { // Don't do anything if it is already showing
        jQuery('.food-content').hide(); // Close all other .food-content
        thisContent.slideDown(function(){
            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: thisContent.offset().top})
        });
    }
});
```